# How to disable Kendo UI Multiselect option? Any JSFiddle example?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, kendo-ui

I am not able to disable particular option item of kendo ui multiselect control in document.ready() function. Following code does not disable Item1 on load.

```
<select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    <option disabled="disabled">Item1</option>
    <option>Item2</option>
</select>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/forums/disabling-one-or-multiple-options

Comment: This doesn't help :-(

Comment: So basically, there is no disabling feature yet. You can only hide the options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable an option before you initialize the multiselect:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#multiselect option").eq(0).prop("disabled", "disabled");        
    $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({});
  });
```

However, if the multiselect is already initialized, then you need to destroy the widget, update the option and re-initialize the widget:

```
<div id="msCont">  
  <select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Item1</option>
    <option value="2">Item2</option>
    <option value="3">Item3</option>
    <option value="4">Item4</option>
    <option value="5">Item5</option>
  </select>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Init widget
    $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({});
    //Destroy widget
    var multiselect = $("#multiselect").data("kendoMultiSelect");
    multiselect.destroy();
    //KendoUI seems to leave behind some widget divs, so remove them
    // using container div as selector
    $("#msCont").find(".k-multiselect-wrap").remove();
    $("#msCont").prepend($("#multiselect")).find(".k-widget").remove();
    //update the option and re-initialize
    $("#multiselect option").eq(0).prop("disabled", "disabled");        
    $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({});     
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/UroTU)**

Comment: Hello.. Thanks for the reply. I ran your demo but its actually removing a option from list instead of disabling it.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a similar workaround for my project, and I found a pretty simple solution without the need of re-initializing the widget. I leave it here, if anyone needs it:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/disable-multiselect-items

I know that some might snap at me if I only leave a link, not the code, so here it is:

```
<select id="select"></select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function onSelect(e) {
              if(e.dataItem.unselectableItem)
              {
                //prevent selection by cancelling the event
                e.preventDefault();
                //prevent closing by setting the autoClose property
                // https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect/configuration/autoclose
                this.setOptions({autoClose: false});
              }
              else {
                this.setOptions({autoClose: true});
              }
        };

        var data = [
            { text: "Disabled", value:"1", unselectableItem: true },
            { text: "Enabled", value:"2", unselectableItem: false }
        ];

        $("#select").kendoMultiSelect({
            dataTextField: "text",
            dataValueField: "value",
            dataSource: data,
            select: onSelect,
            // Set a template to visually distinguish disabled items for the user.
            template: kendo.template($("#template").html())
        });
    });
</script>

<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <span class="#: unselectableItem ? 'k-state-disabled': ''#">
     #: text #
    </span>
</script>
```